# How to share a ZFS formatted USB disk thru a Raspberry-Pi device

Tags: raspberry-pi, nas, zfs

I have a ZFS formatted USB disk that I would like to share on the home network and have an unused Raspberry-Pi (512MB) that is surely not the fastest computer I have but is also surely the one that consume less.

Wake up on LAN request would be a nice feature and hope the USB drive can be put a sleep if not used for some time.

The question is what distribution to use for IT / how to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest using ZFS on a 32 bit system with 512 MB RAM.

You need at least 1GB, and a 64 bit processor is highly recommended. FreeBSD / ARM doesn't seem to do well with ZFS at this point, so Debian on ARM would be your best best, but even then... I wouldn't trust it with data.

Reference: [ZFSTuningGuide](https://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFSTuningGuide)